# Spring 4 websocket And stomp - controller is not reached

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I'm using the official example (Greeting example) of spring located in:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

everything seems to work just fine, when i press the connect i can see that the connection agaisnt the server is being made.

But, after connection when i submit a "name" to the server i get no error and no request reaches the    GreetingController.

I tried to put the log level on trace and i see the following lines when i execute the "send":

```
22 Ar 2014 17:10:52 DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
22 Apr 2014 17:10:52 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
22 Apr 2014 17:10:52 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
22 Apr 2014 17:10:52 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
22 Apr 2014 17:10:52 DEBUG LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator - Connection established, SockJS session id=taxwn2fu, uri=/MyWebApp/hello/535/taxwn2fu/websocket
22 Apr 2014 17:10:52 DEBUG SubProtocolWebSocketHandler - Started WebSocket session=taxwn2fu, number  of sessions=1
22 Apr 2014 17:10:53 DEBUG StompDecoder - Decoded [Payload byte[0]][Headers={stompCommand=CONNECT, nativeHeaders={heart-beat=[10000,10000], accept-version=[1.1,1.0]}, simpMessageType=CONNECT,  id=0686dda9-afa3-7a54-756c-89279ea33126, timestamp=1398175853000}]
22 Apr 2014 17:10:53 DEBUG StompEncoder - Encoded STOMP command=CONNECTED headers={heart-beat=[0,0], version=[1.1]}
22 Apr 2014 17:10:53 DEBUG StompDecoder - Decoded [Payload byte[0]][Headers={stompCommand=SUBSCRIBE, nativeHeaders={id=[sub-0], destination=[/topic/greetings]}, simpMessageType=SUBSCRIBE, simpSubscriptionId=sub-0, simpDestination=/topic/greetings, id=653538d3-0722-0325-2c23-8314abd70cc0, timestamp=1398175853008}]
22 Apr 2014 17:10:53 DEBUG DefaultSubscriptionRegistry - Adding subscription id=sub-0, destination=/topic/greetings
22 Apr 2014 17:10:56 DEBUG StompDecoder - Decoded [Payload byte[17]][Headers={stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={content-length=[17], destination=[/app/hello]}, simpMessageType=MESSAGE, simpDestination=/app/hello, id=f9a608c0-6e02-7828-a057-a6b2b07b6af7, timestamp=1398175856489}]
22 Apr 2014 17:10:56 DEBUG SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler - Handling message, lookupDestination=/hello
```

any ideas?

P.S , here is the part of the js code i use (identical to the website):

```
    function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('/MyWebApp/hello');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
    }

    function disconnect() {
        stompClient.disconnect();
        setConnected(false);
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }

    function sendName() {
        debugger;
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I had a spring configuration problem, i didn't scan the necessary beans directory.

Comment: Can you at least write where did you put `@ComponentScan` annotation and why?

Comment: Have the same issue, and update the vaule of @ComponentScan on spring application class, such as HelloApp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the server is catching the message but it is doing nothing with that.So, I think that you should:

1. Pay attention to this line "config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");" on WebSocketConfig class;
2. Be sure that your Controller is anottated with @Controller and the method with @MessageMapping("/hello");